# Is it possible to give an endorsement via text message or email?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, student-pilot, cfi, logbook-endorsements

Is it possible to give an endorsement to student pilot via email or text message?

For example, I gave an endorsement to my student for a XC. However, he stuck at the destination airport after the weather gets bad. On the next day, the weather became good enough to come back. But, he needs another XC endorsement to fly solo.

1. How can he receive an endorsement to come back?
2. Is it possible to send an endorsement via text message or email?
3. Is it okay to receive an endorsement from somebody CFI at the destination airport? (Let's say they don't know each other.)

That would be great if someone could help me!

Comment: this may be a dumb question, but isn’t the original endorsement good for the return leg as well?  Or do they expire after 24 hours?

Comment: For questions about regulations and what's legally possible, please *always* tell us which country or regulations you're asking about. I've added the faa-regulations tag to your question because it looks like that's what you're asking about. If I'm wrong, please edit your question to add the correct information.

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19217/62) might answer what you're asking. At least questions 1 and 2; for question 3 see [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/43013/62).

Answer (score 2):

Easy, peasy. Fill out a label/sticker with the endorsement printed on it. Then, all you have to do is sign it and place your CFI number on it. You can then either scan it or take a photo of it. Your student can upload the scanned document or photo into an electronic logbook. If they do not have an electronic logbook, they can print out the endorsement at the FBO to put into their paper logbook. When you and the student are together again, you can place the actual label/sticker in their logbook. Alternatively, you can use regular paper. Then you can cut the endorsement into a manageable size and tape it into the logbook. Also, if you and your student use the same software for your electronic logbooks, many have a function to sign endorsements electronically even at a distance (through the internet).

Comment: Thank you again Dean F. That is great explanation!!