# Lost Logbook, but have all flight information on ZuluLog

Tags: flight-training, flight-school, far-61, logbook-endorsements

Good afternoon everyone.

Back in 2013 / 2014 I did Part 61 training in WA State. I had to stop due to financial difficulties at that time.

I moved to Phoenix 6 years ago, and now that I want to get back in to finishing up, discovered my Logbook is nowhere to be found.

I have always been smart enough to log in to ZuluLog and record my time for that flight, what we did, airports we went to, etc.

I contacted the school in WA State, and my flight records are before they went to FSP for their scheduling. I was told they "should" be available in their Loft, and someone would have to go research. I am still waiting since I contacted them 05-NOV-21 for even a response to my email. Whenever I call, I always get someone else who says they know nothing about it, have never seen an email, etc. etc. Even the instructors I did my schooling with are no longer with that place, and it has been sold / bought three different times since my last flight.

My question is this... Since I have everything saved in ZuluLog, is there any way to use that to incorporate a new logbook? I have done a couple flights out here in Phoenix to try and get a feel for a school I want to continue on with.

I've got 50+ hours from my previous training that I just don't want to lose and have to start over unless I absolutely have to.

I appreciate the info and direction anyone can give.

Have a great day, and stay safe up there!

Comment: I am not a pilot and know very little about the regulations regarding pilot training. But looking at ZuluLog's website, it seems like they **are a logbook** and (it would appear to me) you could use them only, without ever writing down anything in a paper logbook, and it would be perfectly legal. Do you have any reason to doubt this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

We already have [a question on replacing a lost logbook](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/767/62), although I'm assuming your main concern is how/if to use the information in ZuluLog to rebuild your paper logbook.

The key point here is that [ZuluLog](https://www.zululog.com/) *is* a logbook (it even says so on their website). The FAA doesn't say anything about how or where you maintain your logbook, and [an electronic one is completely fine to use](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19217/is-it-legal-to-use-an-online-logbook) and very common. So if all your time is recorded in it then you haven't lost anything. My advice is to continue to use ZuluLog or another electronic logbook as your primary one. It makes everything much easier with tracking and reporting hours and other details for checkrides, insurance, flying clubs, currency etc. Most online logbooks allow your instructor to do electronic endorsements too.

Having said that, I guess there were handwritten instructor endorsements in your paper logbook to record your training and it sounds like there's no easy way to track down the instructor(s). Realistically, after 8-9 years that probably doesn't matter much because you'll be starting more or less from scratch with a new instructor anyway.

A lot of logging is effectively on the honor system because there's no objective way to validate it. If the hours in ZuluLog do end up being necessary for your checkride it seems to me like a simple explanation to the DPE and they're unlikely to challenge you on it. If it bothers you, you could consider adding a comment to ZuluLog stating that "training flights and endorsements prior to MM/DD/YYYY were recorded in a paper logbook that was lost in YYYY". You could even write and sign that on paper, then take a photo and upload it to ZuluLog (I assume; I don't know how it works), as a kind of formal statement/record of events.

Comment: Yes sir, that was the synopsis of my question. I have every single minute I flew in Zululog. Tail #, CGI I flew with, etc. Only issue is no endorsement, so I didn't know if it was usable or not. Here in AZ, I have only found a couple CFI's that know what the hell Zululog is. The 1st school I went to get a feel for, didn't even know what BasicMed is., and my Zululog was not acceptable, I would have to start over from scratch with them. Seems that doing schooling in Class G Airspace, the CFI's are a bit more knowledgeable. Either that, or it's just the young 20'ish CFI's nowadays. LOL

Answer (score 1):

There are no specific FAA/FAR regulations regarding lost logbooks and how to reconcile your flight time, endorsements, etc. However, there is published guidance from the FAA regarding how to deal with this issue:

[Here is a link to the information shown below](https://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=8900.1,Vol.5,Ch1,Sec8) regarding lost Pilot Logbooks from the FAA Order 8900.1:

> 5-171      GENERAL. Aeronautical training and experience that is used by airmen to meet the requirements for a certificate or rating, or for recent flight experience, must be documented in a reliable record. This section provides guidance to operations inspectors on the requirement for airmen possession of logbook records and replacement of pilot flight experience records. A pilot logbook is the primary evidence of pilot experience; however, inspectors may accept operator records in lieu of a personal pilot logbook. Pilot logbooks or those company records used to meet the recordkeeping requirements of 14 CFR part 61, § 61.51 may be inspected upon reasonable request by the Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) Administrator, an authorized representative of the National Transportation Safety Board (NTSB), or any state or local law enforcement officer.
>
> 5-172      LOST LOGBOOKS OR FLIGHT RECORDS. Inspectors should advise airmen that they may reconstruct lost logbooks or flight records by providing a signed statement of previous flight time.
>
> A.     Proof of Experience. Airmen may use the following items to substantiate flight time and experience:
>
> - Aircraft logbooks,
> - Receipts for aircraft rentals,
> - Operator records,
> - Copies of airman medical files, and
> - Copies of FAA Form 8710‑1, Airman Certificate and/or Rating Application.
>
> B.     Obtaining File Copies. Airmen who have lost their logbooks or flight records may request copies of their files from the FAA by writing to the following:
>
> FAA Airmen Certification Branch, AFS-760
> P.O. Box 25082
> Oklahoma City, OK 73125
>
> or
>
> FAA Aeromedical Certification
> P.O. Box 25082
> Oklahoma City, OK 73125
>
> NOTE: Inspectors should encourage pilots to complete the flight time sections of official record forms, even though it would not be required for that specific certificate. These records document a chronological development of flight time in case personal records become lost.

Comment: @Jamiec - Thank you. I found an article on AOPA that had a broken link about reconstructing logbooks, and did some searching and couldn't find an updated one. I appreciate the link. I will write to that FAA address and see what I get back from them. Since I was just about to do my check ride and was still a student pilot, I doubt they would have anything on file other than my SP Cert and original 3rd Class Medical, but I will give it a shot. Thanks again.